# Removing XML tags from FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am getting data from a sql string to make an XML file, here is my SQL

```
SELECT [data] AS data
FROM MyTable 
WHERE [Status] = '1' 
FOR XML PATH('DataLocation')
```

And here is my XML return

```
<DataLocation>
  <data>String</data>
</DataLocation>
```

The problem I have is I want to have the tags `DataLocation` but not the tag `data`, I just want to show the `String` value.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you want if there's more than one matching row?

Comment: @AakashM I dont need the <data> tag i just need the value "String" All i want is the <DataLocation> Tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways which lead to the same result. All of them have there tiny goods and bads:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Data NVARCHAR(100), [Status] INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl(Data, [Status]) VALUES 
 ('test 1 with 1', 1)
,('test 1 with 2', 2)
,('test 2 with 1', 1);

SELECT [data] AS [*]
FROM @tbl
WHERE [Status] = 1
FOR XML PATH('DataLocation');

SELECT [data] AS [node()]
FROM @tbl
WHERE [Status] = 1
FOR XML PATH('DataLocation');

SELECT '' + [data] --Any kind of computation results in "no caption name"
FROM @tbl
WHERE [Status] = 1
FOR XML PATH('DataLocation') 

SELECT [data] AS DataLocation
FROM @tbl
WHERE [Status] = 1
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Little background: If there is a column name it will be used. So you have to find a way do get rid of this column name, or replace it with the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

The result will be wrapped in an xml-element with the name of the column, which in turn will be wrapped in the value of `XML PATH`.

This should work:

```
SELECT [data] as 'DataLocation'
FROM MyTable
WHERE [Status] = '1' 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: This isn't working, but its given me a good logic to look for and a better understanding. Thank you Edit: heres the error --  Column name ' ' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML;

Comment: This actually wraps the data from select in another tag

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, what you actually want is a single string value within a `DataLocation` tag. So all you need is

```
SELECT data AS DataLocation
FROM MyTable
WHERE Status = '1'
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

Note that if your table has multiple matching rows, you will get multiple `DataLocation` tags output; you can use an additional `, ROOT('whatever')` to surround these tags with a root element.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you looking for this ?

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(Data NVARCHAR(256), [Status] NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @MyTable(Data, [Status])
VALUES ('String', '1'), ('String1', '1'), ('String2', '1'), ('String3', '1'), ('String4', '2') 

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ' ' + Data FROM @MyTable WHERE [Status] = '1' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS DataLocation FOR XML PATH('')
```

Result

```
<DataLocation>String String1 String2 String3</DataLocation>
```

Answer (score 1):

This thread helped me solve a similar problem; maybe someone else has the same problem:

In the case that the column 'data' is itself an XML datatype, you may find yourself with an additional XML tag that you don't want:

```
SELECT [data] AS data
FROM MyTable
WHERE Status = '1'
FOR XML PATH('DataLocation')
```

Say 'data' contains 'bar'. Then the above query will return:

```
<DataLocation><data><foo>bar</foo></data></DataLocation>
```

If you only want the following returned:

```
<foo>bar</foo>
```

Then change the query to this:

```
SELECT CAST([data] AS XML)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Status = '1'
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to come back to SO to look for this question again, as it's been years since I've had to use FOR XML, but one thing that a lot of customers want is a good User Experience, with the data. For that end, I've developed this little version of your code, with the added feature of comma delimited values.

```
SELECT STUFF(
        (SELECT ', ' + [data] AS data 
         FROM MyTable 
         WHERE Status = '1' 
         FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')
```

Obviously the true answer, was already answered above - `PATH('')`.

However, using [STUFF()](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_sqlserver_stuff.asp) allows me to separate the values with a comma delimiter (or it can be anything you want), and it removes the 1st comma from the string.

I think customers would rather see

> Apples, Oranges, Pears

rather than

> Apples,Oranges,Pears

or worse

> ApplesOrangesPears